# Переименовать таблицу в Firebird

Tags: c#, firebird

Необходимо переименовать таблицу в firebird v3.0

Вычитал на форумах и документации, что в firebird отсутствует возможность переименовывать таблицы, и это делать нужно путем пересоздания таблицы.

Написал 3 запроса, занимающиеся: Созданием новой таблицы, переливанием данных из старой таблицы в новую и удалением старой таблицы. Запросы выполняются последовательно.

Однако при попытке удалить таблицу выдается ошибка: "unsuccessful metadata update ojbect table "mytable1" is in use

Не понимаю в чем ошибка. Если выполнять пошагово и сделать некоторую паузу между перелитием данных и удалением старой таблицы - то выполняется без ошибок.

Как можно сделать паузу до тех пор, пока firebird отпустит таблицу? Или как правильно за один проход сделать переименование?

Запрос-1

```
create table mytable1 (id integer, name varchar(100))
```

Запрос-2

```
insert into mytable2 (id, name) select id, name from mytable1
```

Запрос-3

```
drop table mytable1
```

Спасибо за помощь

PS: Запросы выполняются при помощи [.net провайдера](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/)

Comment: Зачем такое вообще может понадобиться?

Comment: Изменение формата базы данных, оптимизация и прочее. Некоторые таблицы назывались не очень адекватно относительно содержимого в них.

Comment: А почему вы делаете это в .NET-коде? Вы пишете одноразовое приложение? Смысл? Воспользуйтесь существующими решениями, например, IBExpert

Comment: Баз около 10000 штук. Пакерное изменение, с прогрессбаром и оценкой времени окончания, потому как это конвертирование займет больше недели.

Comment: Подсказали, что лучше такие вещи выполнять через ISQL, попробую, может проблема отпадет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка может быть вызвана тем, что какие-то объекты ссылаются на вашу таблицу.

Например, хранимые процедуры и представления можно найти таким запросом

```
SELECT * FROM RDB$DEPENDENCIES D
WHERE D.RDB$DEPENDED_ON_NAME = 'mytable1'
```

а внешние ключи - таким

```
SELECT * FROM RDB$REF_CONSTRAINTS RC
INNER JOIN RDB$INDICES I
  ON I.RDB$INDEX_NAME = RC.RDB$CONST_NAME_UQ
WHERE I.RDB$RELATION_NAME = 'mytable1'
```